# Login History for Self-Service users

Tags: user-management, portal

I am trying to capture the self service portal users activity on a weekly / monthly basis.
The only thing I managed to get is a "Last Login" report , but the problem is that if a user logs in this week, it reduces the number of people logged in last week…

I know this information is visible in "Regular" SF users (via the "Login History" section and in reports), is it possible to get this report for Self-Service users? is this data stored anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a ready made solution currently.

Take a look at this. Can you can write some APEX code to obtain this information?

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm

Else check this link. The last post has detailed explanation of how to accomplish this using a custom object and then creating a report but it will have some storage overhead to think about.

http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=08730000000GwmoAAC

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Data Loader or any other API client that supports SOQL queries (like Workbench)

```
SELECT ApiType, ApiVersion, Application, AuthenticationServiceId, Browser, 
       CipherSuite, ClientVersion, CountryIso, Id, LoginGeoId, LoginTime, 
       LoginType, LoginUrl, NetworkId, OptionsIsGet, OptionsIsPost, Platform, 
       SourceIp, Status, TlsProtocol, UserId 
FROM LoginHistory 
WHERE  LoginTime = LAST_N_MONTHS:6 AND LoginType = 'Self-Service'
```

Or ..

you can use `Setup | LoginHistory` and construct your own list view using LoginType = `Self-Service`

Note that contrary to the [LoginHistory object documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm?search_text=loginhistory), the value of LoginType is `Self-Service`, not `SelfService`. Only 6 months of loginhistory are available.